# Filter Table with JQuery using the “each” element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

OK everybody, I hope you can help me. I have a problem with JQuery or better with the `each` selector of JQuery.

I have an example table, where I want to filter for special values which I entered before. Those values I got from my input field , store them in a variable, split the data an create an JQuery Object. 
Well and then I think I have a problem with the selection, marked in the code section.

```
<p>
    <input id="testyear" size="4" type="text">
    <input value="Werte" onclick="getvalue()" type="button">
</p>
<script>
    function getvalue() {
        var wert = $('#testyear').val();
        $("#years").find("tr").hide();
        var data = this.value.split(" ");
        // create jQuery Object
        var jQueryObject = $("#years").find("tr");
        // i think here is my error, i want to display only the object which are equal or better stored in my variable “wert”.
        $.each(data, function (){
            //jQueryObject = jQueryObject.filter(wert);
            jQueryObject == wert;

    });
    jQueryObject.show();
};
```

```
<!--Example Table-->
<table id="years">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>1997</td>
        <td class="century">20</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2001</td>
        <td class="century">21</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I expect, that when I enter 1997 in the inpt field, the whole tr which contains 1997 will be displayed. I know it is simple but I have no idea so thanks for your help.

Comment: `this.value` is referring to the button value, why?

Comment: you are right, i don`t need this. the value should be as example 1997 and after that it should only display the row where 1997 is loacted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) on the `TR`'s after initially hiding them all.

e.g.

```
 getvalue = function() {
  var wert = $('#testyear').val();
  // create jQuery Object
  $("#years tr").hide().filter(function() {
    return ~~$("td", this).first().text() >= wert;
  }).show();
};
```

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/h8Lejfac/

### Notes:

- The `~~` is a little conversion to integer trick
- You seem to have extra code you do not need in the example
- Just get `filter` to return `true` for each item you want to keep and false for the rest
- When using jQuery, avoid using inline event handlers (like `onclick=`). Use jQuery event handlers instead. See below:

e.g.

```
$('#wert').click(function() {
  var wert = $('#testyear').val();
  // create jQuery Object
  $("#years tr").hide().filter(function() {
    return ~~$("td", this).first().text() >= wert;
  }).show();
});
```

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/h8Lejfac/1/

Comment: thank you for your solution, but i am sorry to say it will now work. there is no output. when i enter in your fiddle 1997 nothing happens, but when i enter 1999 the row of 1997 is missing hm..  do you have another idea ?

Comment: ok, got it i changed the operators to == which marks the exact value. thank you for that. in your example it shows all the results biger then.  thanks for that cheers ch

Comment: @Mchoeti: I was going by your description `"which are equal or better"` :)

Comment: yes you are right, my mistake, thank anyway. no we have a way which is working. thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is not in `each()` method (not selector). Your problem is here:

```
   var data = this.value.split(" ");
```

`this` is not defined (you are not in an object scope). I think you need this:

```
   var data = wert.split(" ");
   -----------^^^^
```

You've obtain the value of `wert` in the last line.